# multiple archive_command in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, master-master-replication, archive-log

I have replication with PostgreSQL, so I want to set `archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/archive/%f'` but I also want to save WAL files to another safe place: S3.

So is it possible to have multiple `archive_command`s? And can I put this command on the slave to push wal files to S3 instead of on the master - I want master to have less performance impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple `archive_command`s:

```
archive_command = 'cp %p /.../%f && (command to archive to S3)'
```

The `&&` is interpreted by the shell. If the `cp` has a non-zero return code, that will be the result of `archive_command`. If the result is 0 (success), the second command is executed, and its return code will be the result of `archive_command`.

You can also defer archiving to S3 to the standby server, but then you have to set `archive_mode = always` there. The disadvantage is that the configuration on primary and standby will be different, which makes failover more complicated. Does the command to archive a file to S3 really cause a substantial performance impact?

Comment: I'm not sure that s3 command to transfer file from master to cloud would cause performance issue or not but just in case I don't want to mess with master but thanks for your answer that answered the question.